# Drop-down list in Word doesn't look like it

Tags: drop-down-menu, ms-word, user-controls

Using Word 365, I entered a drop-down box into a document. I added entries to the list, and it works fine, but it looks like this:

[image]

That word "Select" is all that is visible of the drop-down. No arrow button, no border, nothing.

- Why can't I display the drop-down arrow?
- Is there a way to make the border visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option I am aware of is to change the **Show As** property on the Content Control dialog to Start/End Tag.

This will clearly distinguish the control from other surrounding text in the document.

Comment: True, but it looks really clunky. Thanks, though.

Comment: You probably could put the control inside a Text Box and then color or thicken the border to make it standout.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it's off-topic here and should be closed. The question should be posted in an appropriate end-user forum.

Comment: I feel that adding and formatting a control such as a dropdown box is closer to "programming" than it is to "end user"